# Determine the ideal of the algebraic set $V(X^2Y, (X-1)(Y+1)^2)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification

I want to determine the ideal of $V(X^2Y, (X-1)(Y+1)^2)$. I know algebraic geometry only at a very beginner level so I'm sorry in advance if my argument is trivially flawed.

This is what I've done:
First I figured out that I can determine the ideal of $V(XY, (X-1)(Y+1))$ instead. Then, based on the properties of the function $V$, we have $V(XY, (X-1)(Y+1)) = V(XY) \cap V((X-1)(Y+1))$. But $V(XY)$ has two irreducible parts, namely $x$-axis and $y$-axis and therefore the part that restricts us is $V((X-1)(Y+1))$.

Now $V((X-1)(Y+1)) = V(X-1) \cup V(Y+1)$, and since $X-1$ and $Y+1$ are both irreducible, we have:

$I(V(X-1)) \cup I(V(Y+1)) = \langle X-1, Y+1\rangle$.

I feel that my approach, if one could call this an approach, is very flawed. I would appreciate if someone could help me find my mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that your question is equivalent to checking if the ideal $\langle XY, (X-1)(Y+1)\rangle$ is radical. One possible solution:

$$
\langle XY, (X-1)(Y+1)\rangle = \langle XY, XY - Y + X -1\rangle = \langle XY, X - Y - 1\rangle = \langle Y(Y+1), X - Y -1\rangle.
$$
Now we look at the quotient ring
$$
k[X,Y]/\langle Y(Y+1), X - Y - 1\rangle \cong k[Y]/\langle Y(Y+1) \rangle \cong k \times k.
$$
The first isomorphism holds, because the equation $X - Y -1 = 0$ can written as $X = Y+1$, which expresses $X$ as a polynomial function of other variables, so it is not needed in the quotient.

But $k\times k$ is a ring with no non-zero nilpotents.

I don't think there is a way to write $\langle XY, (X-1)(Y+1)\rangle$ in a simpler form. As you noticed, $V(XY)$ is just the union of the two axes, and $V((X-1)(Y+1))$ is just the union of the lines $X = 1$, and $Y = -1$. These two algebraic sets meet at two points $(1,0)$ and $(0,-1)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. One more question: the original problem asks to determine the ideal of the given affine algebraic set. Am I in the right direction when I approach this as a problem to find the irreducible components of $V$ which results in prime ideals which are their own generators?

Comment: @MahanMehravard Yes, your direction is correct. I wrote that $V(XY, (X-1)(Y+1))$ is just the union of two points $(1,0)$ and $(0,-1)$. Another solution would be to write the ideal  $\langle XY, (X-1)(Y+1)\rangle$ as the intersection of two prime ideals $p_1$ and $p_2$, where $V(p_1) = \{(1,0)\}$ and $V(p_2) = \{(0,-1)\}$. You can figure out what the ideals $p_1, p_2$ are.

Comment: Thank you so much.